# OMS Agent for Kubernetes deploying into kube-system namespace

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

The solution to deploy the OMS Agent into a Kubernetes (OpenShift) cluster is creating a Replica Set and Daemon Set in the kube-system namespace. I am using the Helm method to deploy and specifying the -n parameter gets ignored.

I suppose it's not a massive problem but I would like to keep thing tidy and easily identifiable namespaces as we are a large team.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-hybrid-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMS agent is the managed component, it should be part of kube-system namespace. If moved to any namespace there will be issues for data collection and monitoring.This is by design at the moment because we use the same agent for AKS and non-AKS.

Comment: Hello @SwathiDhanwada. I have onboarded an ARO cluster in the container insight, I have deployed the Oms Agent (Linux) using DeamonSet in the omslogging namespace. I do see the agent pods in the log workspace but in the container insight there is no data been collected . do you know why?